# Is there a way to use Azure DevOps Test Plan parameters for each test case as part of automate testing from visual studio?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, parameters, azure-devops, test-data, test-plan

One of my automated testing projects is looking to use parameters under Azure DevOps Test Plan as an input for each test case and whenever test case would be run from visual studio, it should pick data from Azure DevOps Test Plan parameters.

Comment: Hi @Om Taori, do you mind sharing some screenshots here? Such as the Azure DevOps Test Plan parameters you want to use and other. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?